# PHP versions "market share"

Tags: php, version

Does anyone know where can I find recent data on PHP4 vs PHP5 "market share", that is, what percentage of servers on the Internet have PHP5 installed?

I found this but it's from 2008:
http://www.nexen.net/chiffres_cles/phpversion/18824-php_statistics_for_october_2008.php

I also checked netcraft.com but I don't think they have something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're really concerned about backwards functionality, just use PHP4 features unless your application really needs PHP5 functionality. Otherwise, write something good enough that people will want to upgrade if they [inexplicably] haven't done so yet. :)

Comment: Good question.  As far as I know most hosts support both but really no numbers out there that I can find.

Comment: @dannysauer - Your comment is only partially true. When someone uses PHP 4, they need to "prepare" the environment; PHP4-specific code.

Comment: @Christian - I'm not sure what you're referring to. "Preparing" the environment makes it sound like you're doing some messy version detection instead of just using functionality present in the version you're using; exactly the kind of thing I was suggesting against. ;)

Comment: @dannysauer - Not at all. As you may or may not know, PHP 4 had some serious flaws with leaking variables (registering variables using GET), for instance. If someone is developing something for both 4 and 5, he'd have to start by ensuring variables, cookies etc haven't messed up with....for the sake of security mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When posting the question I forgot that I can compile my own stats which for me would be even more relevant than some global "market share" data. 
I'm selling a PHP script and I have the site urls of the people who buy or trial my software so I can easily do an automated "survey". 
Currently the PHP versions supported by the script are 4.3+. The actual distribution of PHP versions, however, got me surprised (pleasantly). Out of 176 sites that I pinged, 7% were running PHP4, 3% - PHP 5.1 and the rest 90% - 5.2.4+, which I think is quite nice for anyone thinking about developing just for PHP5.

Of course, my data may be scewed - my users are mostly based in US and are more tech-savvy than the average. Someone with wider target market may have different results but I think the trend is good :)

Oh, and it's worth noting that from 176 sites, precisely 2 (two) were running Windows even though my software works just fine on it :)

Answer (score 7):

You can find up-to-date statistics in W3Techs: http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/all/all
Click on the versions to drill down.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad my selected expertise is at 77% market share and growing, 15 years on ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[GoPHP5](http://www.gophp5.org/) lists the web hosts and projects that support PHP 5.2+

Comment: +1 Good site, interesting and potentially useful info.
-1 Doesn't answer the Asker's question.